# How to export variables from shell script

Tags: bash, shell

How do I export variables from a shell script?

I have created 1.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
export TEST=$TEST:/home/centos/
```

Now when I do sh 1.sh or sudo bash 1.sh it executes successfully.

But Now that I have exported TEST through .sh file I was trying to `echo $TEST` but it does not give anything.

I have gone through all of the solutions I came to know that when I run a 
script it actually calls child process and export in that environment only. But I need to export  the variables in Parent shell.

But when I write same export line in .bashrc and source .bashrc  It works. However in order to make ruby installation automated  I do not want to use source command.
To Install ruby with rbenv I followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-centos-7

Comment: There is no way for a child process to `export` a variable back to its parent shell.  The way to execute a script in the current shell context is `source`/`.`, or issuing commands by hand.  Why does using `source` prevent you from automating the install?

Comment: I am trying to automate the script in such a way that user should not have to log in into server or ssh into VM

Comment: What does exporting a variable have to do with your real question?

Comment: This question is about `bash`, it has nothing to do with `ruby`, `rbenv` or `ruby-on-rails`. Please, un-specify them from tags.

Answer (score 5):

You have to source them using `source 1.sh`, because when you invoke sh, you start a new shell which exits after it's done. Why don't you want to use it? Is there a reason?

Comment: I have been trying to Automate the installation of ruby [link]https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-centos-7 thats why I don't want to use source.

Comment: So... how would the use of source be of any disadvantage? I don't understand what problem the use of source should bring up? Maybe you should clarify what you are trying to do: there is a script that contains your commands to install ruby. Why can't you just use source in that script or just define the variable in it?