# Bash: How to evaluate env variable stored in string varable?

Tags: bash, sh, echo, eval, envsubst

I parsed a string from a docker-compose.yml, stored it in a variable but now I want to resolve it.

Example:

```
export TAG=latest
export image_name_and_tag=some_image_name:$TAG
```

How can I echo $image_name_and_tag?

The answer should be "some_image_name:latest"

tried already:

```
echo ${image_name_and_tag#*:}        # To echo the tag
echo '${image_name_and_tag}' | envsubst
eval "echo $image_name_and_tag"
```

and many more. The problem is with "$" inside the string. Without it, I got it to work.

Comment: Echo what? Your two `export` statements are perfectly ordinary, as is the first `echo` command. Where did the name `single_element` come from?

Comment: sry, just recognized my typo, fixed it

Comment: Cannot reproduce; your example with `envsubst` outputs `some_image_name:latest` for me.

Comment: I don't know what I have done here, everything in my question works now. Thanks for your wasted time, sry again.

Comment: I wonder if you may not have actually exported the variable before using `envsubst`. `envsubst` can't see ordinary shell variables in the shell that ran it.

Comment: But in any case, sometimes it's not worth the bother to figure out what went wrong :)

Comment: The variables are not exported and I run the original code in a shell script, so that is why it works now?

Comment: @AldegarRızvan Are you trying to export variables from a shell script (running as a subprocess) to the parent shell? That won't work; environment variables export *down* to subprocesses, but not *up* to parent processes. See [How to export variables from shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273519/how-to-export-variables-from-shell-script).